# Unable to emit to a specific room and client (Socket.io 2.0.2)

Tags: javascript, node.js, dynamic, socket.io, emit

I am using Socket.io to create a multiplayer game. I have used a generated numerical code to dynamically create and join rooms.

My issue comes about emitting to specific rooms or even specific clients. I am unable to emit to a room (`io.in(room).emit('event')` or `io.to(room).emit('event')` *They are synonyms*). I am however able to `socket.emit('event')` between the server and client just fine. No errors. Simply nothing happens when I use anything but `socket.emit()`, `io.emit()`, and `socket.on('',function(){ this.emit(); })`.

The reason I have to emit to specific rooms is to update all clients in their rooms when a new client has joined. *(I had tried emitting to each socket.id in each room but that does not work)*.

[browser debugger tracking server emitted events](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PmDPp.png)

I have uploaded all the code I have used in my Node.js server in hopes that someone can see the error in my program. I am new to Socket.io and I am not sure about the validity of how I have set up my dynamic rooms.

The room event that does not work is: **connectToRoom**

**Server**

```
 var express = require('express');
 var app = express();
 var http = require('http').Server(app);
 var io = require('socket.io')(http);

 app.get('/',function(req, res) {
     res.sendFile(__dirname + '/client/index.html');
 });
 app.use('/client',express.static(__dirname + '/client'));
 http.listen(3000, function(){
     console.log('listening on localhost:3000');
 });

io.on('connection', function(socket){
    socket.id = Math.random();
    SOCKET_LIST[socket.id]=socket;

    socket.on('create',function(){
        var thisGameId = ( Math.random() * 100000 ) | 0;
        roomNo+=1;
        roomArr[thisGameId]=thisGameId;
        this.emit('createResponse', {gameId: thisGameId, mySocketId: socket.id});
        this.join(thisGameId.toString());
    });

    socket.on('joinRoom',function(data){
        //playerJoinGame(data);
        //io.sockets.in(data.roomKey.toString()).emit('connectToRoom', "You are in room no. "+data.roomKey);
        //socket.to(data.roomKey.toString()).emit('connectToRoom', "You are in room no. "+data.roomKey);
        if( io.nsps['/'].adapter.rooms[data.roomKey]!== undefined ){
            socket.join(data.roomKey.toString());
            SOCKET_LIST[socket.id].username = data.username;
            this.emit('joinRoomResponse',{
                roomKey:data.roomKey
            });
        }
        if(io.nsps['/'].adapter.rooms[data.roomKey]=== undefined){
            this.emit('joinError',{
                message: "This room does not exist."
            });
        }
    });
    socket.on('updateRoom',function(data){
        var clients=io.sockets.adapter.rooms[data.roomKey].sockets;
        var clientsArr=Object.keys(clients);
        for (var clientId in clientsArr ) {
            io.sockets.connected[clientsArr[clientId]].emit('connectToRoom', {
                roomKey:data.roomKey,
                username:data.username
            });
        }

        io.sockets.in(data.roomKey).emit('connectToRoom', {
            roomKey:data.roomKey,
            username:data.username
        });
    });

    socket.on('disconnect',function(){
    delete SOCKET_LIST[socket.id];
    });
});
```

**Client**

```
var socket = io();
var roomKey,username,mySocketId;    
var optionDiv = document.getElementById('optionDiv');
var optionDivCreate = document.getElementById('optionDiv-create');
var optionDivJoin = document.getElementById('optionDiv-join');

var prepDiv = document.getElementById('prepDiv');
var createDiv = document.getElementById('create-Div');
var lobbyDiv = document.getElementById('lobbyDiv');
var createRoomKey = document.getElementById('create-roomKey');
var createPlayers = document.getElementById('create-players');
var joinForm = document.getElementById('join-form');
var joinForm_roomKey = document.getElementById('join-roomKey');
var joinForm_username = document.getElementById('join-username');
var joinForm_submit = document.getElementById('join-form-submit');
var gameDiv = document.getElementById("gameDiv");

optionDivCreate.onclick=function(){
    socket.emit('create');
};
optionDivJoin.onclick=function(){
    optionDiv.style.display='none';
    prepDiv.style.display='inline-block';
    joinForm.style.display='inline-block';
};
socket.on('createResponse',function(data){
    roomKey = data.gameId;
    mySocketId = data.mySocketId;
    optionDiv.style.display='none';
    prepDiv.style.display='inline-block';
    createDiv.style.display='inline-block';
    createRoomKey.innerHTML = roomKey;
});

joinForm_submit.onclick= function(){

};
joinForm.onsubmit = function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    roomKey = joinForm_roomKey.value;
    username = joinForm_username.value;
    socket.emit('joinRoom',{
        roomKey:roomKey,
        username:username
    });
    joinForm_roomKey.value='';
    joinForm_username.value='';
};
socket.on('joinRoomResponse',function(data){
    optionDiv.style.display='none';
    createDiv.style.display='none';
    prepDiv.style.display='none';
    lobbyDiv.style.display='inline-block';
    socket.emit('updateRoom',{
        roomKey:roomKey,
        username:username
    });
});
socket.on('connectToRoom',function(data){
    socket.emit('debug');
    //createPlayers.innerHTML = "<br />"+data.username;
    alert("triggered");
});
socket.on('joinError',function(data){
    alert(data.message);
});
```

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--
To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
and open the template in the editor.
-->
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Prototype</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="optionDiv" style="">
            <button id="optionDiv-create">Create Game</button><br />
            <button id="optionDiv-join">Join Game</button>
        </div>
        <div id="prepDiv" style="display:none;">
            <div id="create-Div" style="display:none;">
                Room Key:<br />
                <h1 id="create-roomKey"></h1>
                <h1 id="create-players"></h1>
            </div>
            <form id="join-form" style="display:none;">
                Username:<br />
                <input id="join-username" type="text" style="width:500px"></input><br />
                Room Key:<br />
                <input id="join-roomKey" type="text" style="width:500px"></input><br />
                <button id="join-form-submit">Join</button>
            </form>
        </div>
        <div id="lobbyDiv" style="display:none;">
            You are in room:<br />
            <h1 id="join-roomKey"></h1><br />
            Players in room:<br />
            <h1 id="join-players"></h1>
        </div>
        <div id="gameDiv" style="display:none;">
            <div id="gameDiv-canvas">
                <canvas id="ctx" width="500" height="500" style="border:1px solid #000000;">
                </canvas>
            </div>
            <div id="gameDiv-chat">
                <div id="chat-text" style="width:500px;height:100px;overflow-y:scroll">
                    <div>
                        Hello!
                    </div>
                </div>
                <form id="chat-form">
                    <input id="chat-input" type="text" style="width:500px"></input>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!--<script src="https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.4.5.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/2.0.2/socket.io.js"></script>-->
        <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
        <script src="/client/js/client.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What exactly does "I'm unable to" mean? Are you getting errors? What happens when you try it? You need to describe the actual problem.

Comment: No errors. Simply nothing happens when I use anything but socket.emit();, io.emit();, and this.emit(); when nested in socket.on('',function(){});.

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax is the following:

```
io.to('some room').emit('some event');
```

Comment: I have tried that before. Along with:
io.sockets.in('room').emit('event');
io.sockets.to('room').emit('event');
Namespaces
io.of('').emit('event');
io.of('/').emit('event');

I have looked around for solutions and although they all say the same thing around the bounds of syntax as you have, my client still does not get triggered by the event.

Comment: Then try it again. And try `socket.emit('connectToRoom')` instead of `io.sockets.connected[clientsArr[clientId]].emit('connectToRoom')`

Comment: socket.emit('event') works fine.
I have looked at the source codes of a few open source socket.io codes. Could the issue be how I have set up socket.io? (I do appreciate your answer very much.)

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved my issue. The issue in this program is the way that I have made my program. The program is coded in a *"non-dynamic room"* manner. I have coded the program to only handle one game instance. Not multiple game instances for each room.

It is due to the fact that I am using one "game" instance for all the rooms. All games in each room will be using the same codes. Because I am running separate unique game instances for each unique room, I also need to create unique code for each corresponding game instance. This program does not create unique codes for each corresponding game instance. Hence it does not work.

I have restructured the program in a modular manner to handle activities for each individual room.